# Filter through ArrayList properly

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Slot>`, this `Slot` class has a public property of type `Upload` which has different statuses. I want to filter through these statuses, so only retrieve the slots from the list where `slots.upload.currentStatus` equals something.

Trying something like this

```
Collection<Slot> filtered = Collections2.filter(this.slots, ?????? ));
```

Could you help?

Comment: What version of java are you using? If Java 8 then this is trivial.

Comment: version 8 I'm using. Also I'm new to java, does it matter that I have an ArrayList not a Collection in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial example that shows one way to filter a collection (In this case a `List`, like yours) in Java 8 by using a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) (More information on using Streams can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Slot> slots = Arrays.asList(new Slot(Upload.YAY), new Slot(Upload.NAY),
            new Slot(Upload.YAY), new Slot(Upload.YAY));

    List<Slot> yaySlots = slots.stream()
            .filter(slot -> slot.upload == Upload.YAY)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In your case, the filter might be something like:

```
slot -> slot.upload.currentStatus.equals(INTERESTING_STATUS)
```

Comment: Downvotes make me sad! :-( :-p This should work, shouldn't it? I've not got a compiler to hand, but it's a pretty trivial example...

Comment: Downvotes make me sad too. Thanks for the example, every piece gets me closer